# Computing homology of smash product of two finite CW complexes .

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Let, $(Y,y)$ be a based CW complex with cells only in even degrees; in particular , $r_i$ cells in each of degree $i$ where $i$ is even .
Let, $(X,x)$ be a finite based CW complex , then find $H_*(X \wedge Y)$ for all $* \in \mathbb N \cup {0}.$

$\mathbf {My \ approach}:$ I could only try that by cellular homology,
$H_i(Y)= \oplus_{r_i} \mathbb Z$ (as all the boundary maps of cellular chain complex of $Y$ are $0$) and let CW dimension of X be $d.$

Then, we are collapsing those cells of $X×Y$ required to construct $X \vee Y$ which in turn homeomorphic to $X×\{y\} \cup \{x\}×Y$ .

Denote cells of $X$ and $Y$ by $e^p$ and $f^q$ respectively . Then all cells of the form $e^{j} ×f^0$ and $e^{0} ×f^j$ getting collapsed .

And, $X \vee Y$ is a subcomplex of $X×Y$ , hence we can apply long exact sequence of relative homology groups .

But, I can't approach further ; we were taught only upto chapter 2 in Hatcher's book and a special case of Künneth formula to find homology of $X×Y$ (in image).

[image]

A small help is warmly appreciated .
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Do you know what the map $H_*(X \vee Y) \rightarrow H_*(X \times Y)$ in terms of the Kunneth theorem?  You can then understand the LES of the pair $(X \times Y, X \vee Y)$

Comment: I am unable to understand this map $(i_*)$ where $i$ is the inclusion map; we were only taught to calculate $H_*(X×Y)$ for some common spaces $X$ and $Y$ like torus, circle and non-orientable surface of genus $g.$

Comment: As you say, the differentials in the cellular complex for $X \times Y$ are trivial because of the assumption on $Y$. If we collapse a subcomplex, the differentials must still be trivial in the new cellular complex. Hence, the cellular complex for $X \wedge Y$ has trivial differential. Can you do the calculation now?

Comment: Let me mention: the Kunneth theorem comes from the observation that the cellular chains $C_*(X \times Y)$ is the same as $C_*(X) \otimes C_*(Y)$. In this case, the differential on the latter is trivial. In general, the differential is nontrivial and so the homology of $C_*(X) \otimes C_*(Y)$ is not $H_*(X) \otimes H_*(Y)$, but instead follows from the (algebraic) Kunneth theorem.

Comment: Okay; actually we were not taught the algebraic Künneth theorem still now .